# CoordintatorLayout - scrollable content in both, AppBar and Layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am creating a view based on `CoordinatorLayout`. The view contains two elements: `View` in `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `RecyclerView` as a content. The whole content is also wrapped in `SwipleRefreshLayout` - there was a problem with scrolling up, but easily fixed (via `OnOffsetChangedListener` in `AppBar`)

My problem is that a view in CollapsingToolbarLayout can be higher than a screen (very rare, but possible), so it has to be scrollable.

See this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <View android:id="@+id/very_big_height"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
                      android:layout_height="2000dp"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dummy_recycler_view"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

When I scroll via an AppBar I can set my layout in such a state:
[image: unexpected behaviour example on device]

The blue area has id `very_big_height` and that white area is actually an empty space on a screen, as my RecyclerView has a `wrap_content` height and no items inside.

I still can scroll the AppBar via the blue area, and even over scroll it completely outside the screen. And if I over scroll it, there is no way to see it again.

My expected behaviour is:
**AppBar should scroll only to the bottom of the screen. It should not hide if there is no content below.**
Also, if content fits screen AppBar should not be scrollable (I've founded solution for disabling scroll when no content, but doesn't work when AppBar doesn't fit the screen.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

the scroll issue is caused by the parent view which is `SwipetoRefreshLayout` , the root view of your `xml` should be `CoordinatorLayout` .

i don't know what is the purpose of using `SwipetoRefreshLayout` , but having to much scrolling element may cause some bad scroll experience

Comment: It's not the reason. Doesn't work without SwipeToRefresh, also, there is a reason why this coordinator layout is wrapped with this layout (like swipe to refresh posibilitty)

Comment: And I want to point that swipe to refresh is must have feature in my case.

Answer (score 0):

First one the CoordinatorLayout can not send scroll event to SwipeRefreshLayout. You can try the code in [ChildCoordinatorLayout](https://github.com/ToDou/nestrefresh/blob/master/nestrefresh/src/main/java/com/todou/nestrefresh/ChildCoordinatorLayout.kt)

Second is that you can set RecyclerView match parent.